# JRuby DSL encapsulation, exclude standard library

Tags: java, ruby, security, jruby, dsl

I'm trying to make a Java program that allows users to do some limited scripting with a Ruby DSL that I've written. The script the user writes is saved to a Proc object in JRuby. The problem arises in that the user can still access methods that are standard to Ruby, such as `File.new`, or creating classes, or basically messing with other internal logic of the program or computer.

Is there a way to limit the user's script to only the constraints of the DSL, using JRuby or Ruby or even Java? Or at least to remove the user's access to certain classes?

Comment: I'm not familiar with jruby, but it seems like the problem should be addressed elsewhere. The big advantage of using Ruby for a DSL is that you get to use Ruby! Restricting access to non-DSL features would kind of defeat the point. If you want to restrict the user, do it at a higher level e.g. restricting the permissions of the program that loads the script so that it can't create files.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're running under JRuby, you can use a [Java security policy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour2/index.html) ([policy file documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html)) to prevent users from being able to do things like file or network I/O. Of course, this will keep your code from having those capabilities, too! You can whitelist code by jar URI or by jar signature, so one tactic is to create a "hull" of trusted code that strongly validates its input, package it in its own jar, trust it, and use it exclusively for your own code. Doing this right gets complicated fast (have an extensive test suite!), but it can be done.

To have explicit control over the namespace available to your DSL, you can use [BasicObject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/BasicObject.html). It doesn't mix in `Kernel` or any of the other things available in the standard Ruby namespace. This doesn't give you *security*, though, because users can still use `::File` directly or `include ::Kernel` to get it all back!